# how to change select box selected value? which means i want to show the selected value, rather than the text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to display the selected value, rather than the text.
like
[image]

instead

[image]

i have tried with below code, but doesn't works for me, any help would be appreciated

```html
<select class="form-control" name="identity" id="identity">
<option value="CC">Cédula de Ciudadanía</option>
<option value="CE">Cédula Extranjera</option>
<option value="NIT">Nit</option>
<option value="TI">Tarjeta de Identidad</option>
<option value="PPN">Pasaporte</option>
<option value="SSN">Número de Seguridad Social</option>
<option value="LIC">Licencia de Conducción</option>
<option value="DNI">DNI</option>
</select>
```

but it sholud not reflect the select box values

Comment: then you have to copy value into text for selected options

Comment: You will have to overwrite the `<option>` tag values and leave as selected the one "CC", but is weird to use it that way... that may not be the solution you are looking for...

Answer (score 1):

- Have a fake `div` element over `select` element
- Set `pointer-events: none;` for `fake` element
- Listen `change` event of `select-element`
- Set the `text` of the `fake` element on change of the `select-element`

```js
var $identity = $('#identity');
var $fake = $('#fake');
$fake.css($identity[0].getBoundingClientRect());
$identity.on('change', function() {
  $fake.text($(this).find('option:selected').text());
}).change();
```

```css
#fake {
  pointer-events: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 3px;
}
#identity {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" name="identity" id="identity">
  <option value="CC">Cédula de Ciudadanía</option>
  <option value="CE">Cédula Extranjera</option>
  <option value="NIT">Nit</option>
  <option value="TI">Tarjeta de Identidad</option>
  <option value="PPN">Pasaporte</option>
  <option value="SSN">Número de Seguridad Social</option>
  <option value="LIC">Licencia de Conducción</option>
  <option value="DNI">DNI</option>
</select>
<div id="fake" style="position:absolute;"></div>
```

Comment: you are awesome bro, Thank u :-)

Comment: @GaneshPutta – I'm glad it helped! _Happy Coding_. Just confirm the Browser Compatibility...

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, this is **not** possible with the native HTML `<select>`. But, you can look for other `<select>` libraries which can do this or write your own `<select>` component which does this.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var $identity = $('#identity');
var $fake = $('#fake');
$fake.css($identity[0].getBoundingClientRect());
$identity.on('change', function() {
  $fake.text($(this).find('option:selected').val());
}).change();
```

```css
#fake {
  pointer-events: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 32px !important;
  line-height: 32px;
}
#identity {
   opacity: 0;
   height: 32px !important;
 
    line-height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" name="identity" id="identity">
  <option value="CC">Cédula de Ciudadanía</option>
  <option value="CE">Cédula Extranjera</option>
  <option value="NIT">Nit</option>
  <option value="TI">Tarjeta de Identidad</option>
  <option value="PPN">Pasaporte</option>
  <option value="SSN">Número de Seguridad Social</option>
  <option value="LIC">Licencia de Conducción</option>
  <option value="DNI">DNI</option>
</select>
<div id="fake" style="position:absolute;"></div>
```